# Doctrine update query with LIMIT

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I would like to do an update-query with a LIMIT like that:

```
UPDATE anytable SET anycolumn = 'anyvalue' WHERE anothercolumn='anothervalue' LIMIT 20
```

How is this possible with doctrine 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not doctrine specific, but maybe possible with a subquery ?

```sql
UPDATE messages SET test_read=1
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id FROM (
         SELECT id FROM messages 
         ORDER BY date_added DESC  
         LIMIT 5, 5
     ) tmp
 );
```

Comment: `SELECT': Error: Class '(' is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

I found I had to fetch the connection from the entityManager and call executeUpdate:

```
$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate(
    "UPDATE anytable SET anycolumn = 'anyvalue'
     WHERE anothercolumn='anothervalue'
     LIMIT 20");
```

The [doctrine page about native queries](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html) says:

> If you want to execute DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT statements the Native
>   SQL API cannot be used and will probably throw errors. Use
>   EntityManager#getConnection() to access the native database connection
>   and call the executeUpdate() method for these queries.

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:**

you can go about it in 2 different ways:

**1 - Create query directly using DQL:**

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery('UPDATE Entities\User u SET u.someValue = newValue WHERE u.id = someId');

// this will add the LIMIT statement
$query->setMaxResults(20);

$query->execute();
```

**2 - Create query using QueryBuilder:**

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

$query = $qb->update('Entities\User', 'u')
            ->set('u.someValue', newValue)
            ->where('u.id = someId')
            ->getQuery();

// this will add the LIMIT statement
$query->setMaxResults(20);   

$query->execute();
```

you should do: echo `$query->getSQL();` to check out the sql generated for these two

**EDIT:**
another alternative (not highly recommended) is to use [Native SQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: No it does not help. I need a query that updates multiple, but not all rows of a table. All that in one query. I dont want to select some and then update one by one.

Comment: @scube see if that's close to what you need

Comment: Your provided way 1 and way 2 do not work. I tried it before posting here. You should have done that, too. Your suggestion of Native SQL works.

Comment: I've just tried something similar but `$query->setMaxResults(20);` doesn't seem to work for update queries - no limit was placed on the update statement that shows in Symfony2's logs.